# I have a Future<List> that returns data from sqlite in flutter. I want to convert this list into ListView. How can I do that

Tags: flutter

I have a Future that returns data from SQLite in a Flutter. I want to convert this list into ListView. How can I do that?

```
  Future<List<Caste>> castes() async {
    final Database db = database;
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('caste');
    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return Caste.n(
        id: maps[i]['id'],
        name: maps[i]['name'],
      );
    });

class CasteListView extends ListView {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [CasteListItem(1, "name"), CasteListItem(2, "Meghya")],
    );
  }
}

class CasteListItem extends ListTile {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  CasteListItem(this.id, this.name);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      onTap: () {
        print(name);
      },
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        child: Text(name[0]),
      ),
      title: Text(name),
    );
  }
}
```

How can I convert?

Answer (score 0):

1. For loading the `castes` use a `FutureBuilder`. With this you can define what is showing while the query is still executing and what to show when you have the results.
2. For showing the data use `ListView.builder()` or `ListView.seperated()`. There you can define how to build the widget for each item.
3. Code could look like:

```
class CasteListView extends ListView {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: castes(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          List<Caste> castes = snapshot.data;
          return ListView.separated(
            itemBuilder: (context, oindex) => CasteListItem(caste.id, caste.name), 
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(), 
            itemCount: castes.length
          );
        }

        return Text("Loading...");
      }
    );
  }
}
```